# R: long to wide transformation using reduce and setting suffixes

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Let's take iris data as example and modify it slightly:

(NOTE: instead of the below two lines use 4 lines from "UPDATE #1" section)

```
data(iris)
iris$id <- rep(1:50, times = 3)
```

I need to transform data from this quazi-long format to a wide format, so that in each row the id is the same. In other words: the original iris data can be regarded as 3 tables (one for each Species) pasted one under the other. I need those 3 tables to be pasted one on the side of the other.

That was easy and I did it this way:

```
require(purrr)
require(dplyr)
iris %>% split(.$Species) %>% reduce( full_join, by = "id")
```

The above example produces names like "Petal.Length.x", ..., "Petal.Length.y", ..., "Petal.Length". I'd prefer them to be: "Petal.Length.setosa", ..., "Petal.Length.versicolor", ..., "Petal.Length.virginica". So the only thing that is left is to append species names to original variable names.

I tried using `map` and `setNames` before `reduce`, but did not succeed.

I don't want to use tidyr's `gather` and `separate`, because my 1.5GB data set grows to 13GB in the pure long format (I have lots of id-like columns that I need to keep).

I could probably add the names in the next line using `names`, `gsub` and some basic regex, but am curious if it is possible to do without breaking the `%>%` flow.

---

UPDATE #1

Thank you for reply, lmo ! A very nice and clean solution! When I first saw it seemed to me that I overthought the problem... but actually I oversimplified it on stackoverflow. Let's add some mess:

```
iris$id <- rep(sample(1:50, 50), times = 3) ## random order
iris$drop_me <- sample(c(1,0), 150, TRUE, c(0.8, 0.2)) ## rows wirh 0 in this column will be missing
iris <- iris[iris$drop_me == 1, ]
iris$drop_me <- NULL
```

So I have the above data and now I try using `reduce`... I also updated from `left_join` to `full_join` since I realised I was skipping some results.

Thank you in advance and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R method using `split` and `do.call`:

```
# get list of data frame, drop the split factor (Species)
myList <- split(iris[, -which(names(iris) == "Species")], iris$Species)
# perform wide transformation
do.call(data.frame, myList)
```

This puts the species names at the front. It would not be too hard to move them to the back using `gsub`.

Here is part of the result:

```
  setosa.Sepal.Length setosa.Sepal.Width setosa.Petal.Length setosa.Petal.Width
1                  5.1                3.5                 1.4                0.2
2                  4.9                3.0                 1.4                0.2
3                  4.7                3.2                 1.3                0.2
4                  4.6                3.1                 1.5                0.2
5                  5.0                3.6                 1.4                0.2
6                  5.4                3.9                 1.7                0.4
```

The other species are additional columns.

*answer for Update #1*

This gets a bit more complicated, though the first line is the same:

```
# get list of data frame, drop the split factor (Species)
myList <- split(iris[, -which(names(iris) == "Species")], iris$Species)
# add names to data.frames
myList <- lapply(names(myList),
                 function(i) {
                       setNames(myList[[i]],
                         c(paste0(head(names(myList[[i]]), -1), ".", i), "id"))
                 })

# merge the data.frames together
Reduce(function(x, y) {merge(x, y, by="id", all=TRUE)}, myList)
```

This results in the naming that you wanted with the Species appended to the end of each variable.

Comment: Than you, lmo ! A very nice and clean solution. I realized, though, that I oversimplified my problem on stack overflow. I updated the question to reflect it correctly. Regards, rpl.